# Where should I ask this Quaternion / Euler Angle question

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I have this question, and I want to be sure to ask it in the right community, but I need help figuring out which one that would be.  As you will see, it is most likely going to be either math, physics, or cs.

**Meta Question**
Where should I ask the following question? :

**Question I want to ask:**  I am getting gyroscope data in the form of rate of change of Euler Angles.  I want to be impervious to Gimbal Lock, so I need to convert these values to Quaternions.  **Question =>** Could someone link me to an algorithm that converts small delta Euler Angles (gyroscope frame) to the corresponding small delta Quaternion to be accumulated constantly with the reference frame Quaternion?

Comment: StackExchange is __NOT__ a forum!

Comment: Can you clarify the purpose of your comment?  And if this is not the place to ask "where should I ask" questions, then where should I ask them?

Comment: You said "in the right forum". StackExchange exist to not be like forums where you have _threads_. Here you have _questions_. And yes, you can ask "where should I ask". Once again, just telling you SE is not a fourm

Comment: Corrected "forum" to "community" in the original question.

Answer (score 1):

The idea of using quaternions *for the purpose of avoiding gimbal lock* sounds to me like a game development thing (at least, that's the only context where I've heard of it before), so you could try [Gamedev SE](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com) if none of Math/Physics/CS seem quite right. They even have a [tag for quaternions](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/quaternion).

Comment: It is important for anything that represents free rotations in 3D.  My application is getting data out of a raw data stream coming from an accelerometer.

Comment: Where I said accelerometer I should have said gyroscope.  It's too late to edit it now.  It is an accelerometer and gyroscope combination, and I am trying to get the change in orientation from the gyroscoe.